# Why multiple common chunks all generate the runtime codes in webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack

Let me be directly, here's the problem:

I have two CommonsChunkPlugin in my webpack.config.js:

```
entry: {
    'vendor': [
        'jquery'
    ],
    'a': 'a',
    'b': 'b'
},

new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    name: 'vendor',

    minChunks: Infinity
}),
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    name: 'common',

    chunks: [
        'a',
        'b'
    ]
})
```

And, which looks fine before being bundled, after that, i got this:

***The runtime codes show up BOTH IN vendor.js AND common.js, which is weird, and that causes error when i load both vendor.js and common.js in my page.***

[image]

Any ideas?

> Plus, webpack 1.15.0 used here. By the way, webpack 2 for this config is doing well.

Comment: This seems similar to https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/multiple-commons-chunks

Comment: @sandyJoshi Yeah, i've tried that, but the difference is that example doesn't use the `minChunks: Infinity` option. Still has problem here.